# Problem Using _.compact lodash to eliminate null values on an array of objects

Tags: angularjs, lodash, angular-google-maps

I'm manipulating an array of objects that i get from an http request containing coordinates to create markers in google-maps , but i need to eliminate all the null values in the array. I'm trying with compact but it gives back the same array unchanged.

//this is the resulting array structure

```
var array=
[{"id":0,"latitude":45.17850875854492,"longitude":7.773523330688477},{"id":1,"latitude":45.122344970703125,"longitude":7.7135162353515625},{"id":2,"latitude":null,"longitude":null},{"id":3,"latitude":45.11630630493164,"longitude":7.730717658996582},{"id":4,"latitude":45.116214752197266,"longitude":7.730687141418457},{"id":5,"latitude":null,"longitude":null}]

var comp =_.compact(array)
```

i dont get any error in the cosole , but the variable comp return the same exact array without removing null values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your values are arrays, and the `null` is a value of your properties. The `_.compact()` method works with primitives.

Use `_.reject()` and check with `_.isNull` if the properties are `null`, and the object should be removed:

```js
const array =
[{"id":0,"latitude":45.17850875854492,"longitude":7.773523330688477},{"id":1,"latitude":45.122344970703125,"longitude":7.7135162353515625},{"id":2,"latitude":null,"longitude":null},{"id":3,"latitude":45.11630630493164,"longitude":7.730717658996582},{"id":4,"latitude":45.116214752197266,"longitude":7.730687141418457},{"id":5,"latitude":null,"longitude":null}]

const result = _.reject(array, ({ latitude, longitude }) =>
  _.isNull(latitude) || _.isNull(longitude)
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ty, it worked , can i use things like _.uniq or _.filter too with this method on this array ?

Comment: You can use `_.filter()`, and `_.uniqBy()` (and other by methods) as long as you state which properties the method should refer to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use _.pickBy()

> Creates an object composed of the object properties predicate returns truthy for

[lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#pickBy)

This applies on object so for an array you can use that:

```
var comp = _.map(array, item => _.pickBy(item));
```